# ng-options getting null value in the drop-down.I'm using for controllers?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm new to angular .I'm passing ng-model for selected option in the drop-down.
My code is

```
<label>Tables</label><select ng-options="option.display for option in 
tableviewOptions" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="getView 
(selectedOption)></select>
```

In this I'm I changed table options the option is not showing as selected in the DOM.

Comment: your `ng-model` has a space ? -- `selected option`.  can you confirm ? [question edited]

Comment: I think that may be OP typo issue. otherwise he got a error

Comment: @rj26 I have edited your question. Please copy past my edited code, then let me know if it's not working

Comment: Please post your model

Comment: Where are you expecting the selected option to be shown? Can you show us that part of the code

Answer (score 0):

we have updated your question. But I have post it as an answer with some changes

like `option.display` is wrong, that should be like below .

```
<label>Tables</label><select ng-options="option as option.display  for option in 
tableviewOptions" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="getView 
(selectedOption)></select>
```

> But if you post your controller code and JSON data , then it could be better to avoid guess answers

Answer (score 0):

@ramesh rajendran thanks for your answer...
Actually my issue with code confirmation in the jsp file.I'm using more than one controller in my application so the the scope value is getting null for me.Later I've rectified my issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-options syntax is wrong.

It's like `ng-options="value as text for option in Options"`
so you have to pass variables accordingly

In your case, if you want to get option.display as value your tag would be

```
    <label>Tables</label>
<select ng-options="option.display as option.display for option in 
    tableviewOptions" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="getView 
    (selectedOption)></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the space by adding this code

select:option:empty
{
display:none
}